# Apache Shiro authentication using encrypted data

Tags: shiro

I'm able to Authenticate user using Apache Shiro by passing username and password. But if i have pass encrypted data, then how will i achieve this?
I have tried the below:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");
    SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();

    SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);

    JcaCipherService jcaCipherService =new DefaultBlockCipherService("RSA") ;
    jcaCipherService.decrypt("UOK4yfsmoavRDq+5NiYuMh2s2KC9GBzUCra4MGIx+7ERbdb0IRGsQZxDza7kir/OAupq18Vzm8cZzaHoKeC/TA==".getBytes(), "MIIBVwIBADANBgkqhk".getBytes());
```

But is it giving me the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.shiro.crypto.CryptoException: Unable to acquire a Java JCA Cipher instance using javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance( "RSA/CBC/PKCS5Padding" ). RSA under this configuration is required for the org.apache.shiro.crypto.DefaultBlockCipherService instance to function.
at org.apache.shiro.crypto.JcaCipherService.newCipherInstance(JcaCipherService.java:414)
at org.apache.shiro.crypto.JcaCipherService.initNewCipher(JcaCipherService.java:591)
at org.apache.shiro.crypto.JcaCipherService.crypt(JcaCipherService.java:444)
at org.apache.shiro.crypto.JcaCipherService.decrypt(JcaCipherService.java:390)
at org.apache.shiro.crypto.JcaCipherService.decrypt(JcaCipherService.java:382)
at com.thbs.esb.authenticate.Authenticate.main(Authenticate.java:24)   


Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/CBC/PKCS5Padding
at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:539)
at org.apache.shiro.crypto.JcaCipherService.newCipherInstance(JcaCipherService.java:408)
... 5 more
```

Comment: can you tell how you encrypted the password? Is the machine encrypting is different from decrypting? If so also provide JDK version for encryption and decryption as might be a JDK issue.

Comment: I have encrypted data using RSA algorithm.

Comment: and for decrypt method, the parameters that are passed is (encryptedData,privateKey)